# Creating, executing, and deleting a docker image in sequence using python

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to use docker to run numerical experiments (eventually on a node like AWS, but let's leave that for now). The code is in python, with some underlying c libraries. The code changes frequently, so the docker image needs to be recreated frequently. Also parameter files change for every experiment I run. I want to use docker to reduce clutter on the machine I run my experiment on.

I don't want to have a docker image per experiment sitting on my hard disk, so I wanted to know if there a way to create, execute, and then delete a docker image in sequence from a python script.

Comment: Why don't you mount your data into the container as a volume?

Comment: I didn't know about volumes! So you mean create an image with all non-changing dependencies, and put the changing dependencies in a volume that is then mounted. Is there an easy way to transport this image+volume to a remote node? I know the image can be tar'd and then loaded on the node.

Comment: You can probably use a Python virtual environment to achieve the same goal, without requiring a complex system service and without requiring root permissions to run your job.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't know how to achieve the same goal using a python virtual env. In a previous attempt, I would set up the environment from the version control system on the node, which would create a bunch of clutter in case of failed jobs, or result in a broken state (is the node busy?). I'd rather set up the environment in a container, execute it on the node, and quit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use python's `subprocess` module to call docker commands necessary in linux/ windows depending on where your docker is. Eg for linux,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["docker", "rmi", "<your-image-name>"])
subprocess.call(["docker", "build", "--tag", "<your-image-name>", "<dir-of-Dockerfile>"])
```

If your machine is Windows, it may need different arguments, which you can find by Googling.